# JHipster Registry - why is it mandatory to run in the cloud for production?

Tags: jhipster

I am working on an app that needs to be self-hosted on a Windows 10 PC where all the clients are inside a company network.  I am using docker-compose for the various microservices and I am considering JHipster for an API Gateway and Registry service.

As I am reading the documentation, there is a line in the JHipster docs (https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/
) that says "You can run a JHipster Registry instance in the cloud. **This is mandatory in production**, but this can also be useful in development".  I am not a cloud expert so I not sure what is different in the environments that would cause the Registry app issues when running on a local PC.  Or perhaps there is a way to give the local Windows PC a 'cloud' environment.

Thanks for any insight you have for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this sentence does not make sense.

Of course, you must run a registry if you generated apps with this option but it does not mean that you must run it in the cloud. The same doc shows you many alternative ways to run it.

Running all your micro services on a single PC is a bit strange, it defeats the purpose of a microservice architecture because you got a single point of failure that can't scale. Basically, you are paying for extra complexity without getting the benefits, where a monolith would be so much simpler and more productive.

How many developers are working on your app?

Comment: Long story.. but my client is interested in hosting this application to run multiple diagnostic instruments in the cloud.   We do have 2 services that we will likely need to scale anyway even if each instrument is stand-alone, either in the cloud or in internal data center.  Also, I like the idea of being able to use out of the box Postgres, RabbitMQ, and Keycloak with docker-compose to make installation and upgrades easier.   So now, I am evaluating if I can/should use the JHipster registry services locally.

Comment: @EricHansen hi! I am running a localhost solution build with jhipster deployed on minikube: https://renanfranca.github.io/i-built-a-baby-care-web-app-using-jhipster.html